# Hiding Directory using OneDrive SDK

Tags: onedrive

Been looking around at the LiveSDK 5.6, I was wondering if there is a way (or if it is even possible) to set the hide attribute in a directory an app creates to hidden/true in a users OneDrive?

Answer (score 3):

OneDrive does not support 'hidden items' such as the way the Windows File System does.